# Google Maps API Javascript Gray Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use google maps API but keep getting a grayed out box instead of a map:

My javascript:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -86.408, lng: 43.077};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('postmap'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true
    });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  });

}
```

This is what I get:[image]

The weird part is some cooridents work and some don't... for example 0 latitude and 0 longitude renders a map.

Comment: Where is the location you are trying to display on the map?  Where did those coordinates come from?  If I reverse the latitude and longitude, I get somplace in Lake Michigan, off the coast of Grand Haven.

Answer (score 0):

*The weird part is some cooridents work and some don't*

some latitudes are valid, and some not.
The valid range for latitudes is about `-85` to `85`

Set the zoom to 0 and you'll see that your marker is outside of the map(earth)

```js
function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -86.408, lng: 43.077};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('postmap'), {
    zoom: 0,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true
    });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  });

}
      

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,body,#postmap{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<div id="postmap"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```